# Error on Environment wrapfigure* while placing figure

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, wrapfig

Anyone can halp about this error ?

> Environment wrapfigure* undefined. \begin{wrapfigure*}

thanks

Tommy

Comment: as it says, the environment is not defined what did you intend it to do?

Comment: I tried this code:

Comment: \begin{wrapfigure*}
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures_M/img9}
\end{wrapfigure*}   Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: Why did you add the `*`?  The manual doesn't say anything about a `*` version..  BTW, whereas macros like \vspace use \@ifstar to detect the `*` option, environments like figure and figure* use two completely different definitions,

Comment: I agree with John Kormylo, I could not find any existence of a `wrapfigure*` environment, at least not within the `wrapfig` package

Comment: OK, while I am using \begin{figue}....\end{figure}, the figure placed on thebottom of the page instead of te spciphic place intwo column document. any solution will be most welcome.

Comment: it is impossible to guess what your problem is as you have provided no example currently it seems to just be a  typo in the environment name which is `wrapfigure` not `wrapfigure*`. If there is another problem you should perhaps ask a new question with a real example test document.

Comment: Hi, I am using two column paper documnet and I want to add figure in second column. while I using only \begin{figure}... after compilation, the figure shown at the bottom of the page at the center. Do you know how to fix it ? while I am using the other option(my first quetion) it adding the figur at the speciphic column but ther is anerrorralated to enviroment...

Comment: As requested by David Carlisle, if you have a different problem, ask a new question. Also, I would advise proofreading your posts to ease communication.